# sorting with bubble sort using 2 function

Tags: c, function, sorting, bubble-sort

At first i used bubble sort to sort some numbers.It worked.And then again i tried to sort using bubble sort with 2 function with same logic.but it is not working.I am new to work with 2/3 function.So can anyone help me to find the problem in my logic?

[**First source**](https://repl.it/@mahinhossen/bubble-sort)

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i,j;
    float num[5], c;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%f",&num[i]);
    }
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            if(num[i]<num[i+1])
            {
                c=num[i];
                num[i]=num[i+1];
                num[i+1]=c;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("%.2f\n",num[i]);
    }
}
```

[**Second source w/function**](https://repl.it/@mahinhossen/Bubblesortwith-2-function)

```
#include<stdio.h>
void sort(int a[]);
void main()
{
    int i;
    double a[3], A, B, C;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf",&a[i]);
    }

    sort(a);

    printf("In The Function\n");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("%.2lf\n",a[i]);
    }

    return;
}

void sort(int a[])
{
    int i, n;
    double temp;

    for(n=0;n<2;n++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]<a[i+1])
            {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Please **NO** external links for code. Paste it here as text and mark it as code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: `... find the problem in my logic?` Check your array indexes, they could be out of bounds.

Comment: Please read & act on hits googing 'stackexchange homework'. Show that your program calculates what you expect it to as it goes through (sub)expressions--including that arguments passed to each function/opertaor meet its requirements--by saying what that is & showing what it actually does via output.

Comment: Beyond the data type problem that kiran points out below, **both** source lists suffer from invoking undefined behavior by accessing their array boundaries beyond their declared dimensions. You probably want to fix that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not ignore the warnings.

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘sort’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     sort(a);
     ^
sort.c:2:6: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘double *’
 void sort(int a[]);
  ^
```

You have declared `a` as `double` but your `function` receives `a` as `int`.
Change it to as below.

```
void sort(double a[]);
```

Comment: sorry i just started working with c.and haven't learnt yet pointer much.so ignored it

Comment: @mahinhossen Compiler warnings are nearly always a sign you're doing something wrong, even for seasoned professional. For a beginner working on the tasks beginners work on, you can be assured warnings are a *guarantee* you're doing something wrong, and should be treated as errors. Don't ignore them; discover what they mean and *fix them*.

Comment: thanks i found it.i didn't  used a as double,that was the mistake.thanks #kiran biradar

Comment: @mahinhossen That isn't the only mistake. Your indexing is wrong as well. your inner loops are breaching the declared boundaries of your array.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the double

```
double a;
sort(a);
```

value in  the main function  but at the function declaration part your datatype is integer

```
void sort(int a[])
```

correct this to

```
void sort(double a[])
```